# Git manually specify parent commits

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

To merge two divergent branches (say I'm on `master` and want to merge `topic`), sometimes it's easier to manually merge files by inspecting `git diff` and applying the changes manually (or parts of them automatically using `git apply`). However, this just changes the working directory files, so my commit will just have current `master` as a parent commit, rather than appearing as a merge commit between `master` and `topic`. Is there a way to manually specify parent commits to `git commit`?

Comment: Besides jthill's answer, you can also go much lower level and run `git write-tree`, `git commit-tree`, and `git update-ref` manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

torek's comment indeed is closest to what I'd prefer:

```
git commit-tree -p <parent1> -p <parent2> -m <message> $(git write-tree)
```

This outputs a new commit hash, that I can use with `git reset --hard <hash>` to get my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The pure handroll setup is

```
git merge -s ours --no-ff --no-commit otherbranch
```

which sets the parents for whatever you commit as the result and leaves all the actual merging to you. If doing touch-up on the automerge will work better for you, leave off the `-s ours`.